# How to tell C# that a struct's non-nullable fields may actually be null for nullability-analysis purposes?

Tags: c#, struct, nullable-reference-types, c#-10.0

Here is an example C# program with nullable reference types enabled:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

MyStruct myStruct = new("A");
List<MyStruct> list = new() { myStruct };
MyStruct found = list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Str == "B");
Console.WriteLine(found.Str.Length);

struct MyStruct
{
    public readonly string Str;

    public MyStruct(string str)
    {
        Str = str;
    }
}
```

Note that `MyStruct` contains a *non-nullable* `Str` field. *In theory* this means that the `Str` field should never be nullable and the compiler will in *almost* all cases warn you if you leave it null.

However, one case in which a null value can slip in is if a non-initialized struct is returned via a generic method, such as with the `FirstOrDefault` call above. In this case, the `Str` field *will* be null but the C# compiler will give no warnings, either when accessing `Str` or when assigning the `found` variable, and thus the program crashes with a `NullReferenceException` when it tries to access `found.Str.Length`. (Another case if when reading a struct from an array.)

To make matters worse, some code analysis tools will falsely caution *against* checking to make sure `found.Str` isn't null. (For example, if I add `if(found.Str != null)` then Resharper will report that as "Expression is always true" and prompt to remove it even though it is definitely not true in this case.)

This seems like a major enough "leak" in C#'s nullability analysis that I have to wonder if I'm missing something about how to make the compiler understand this situation. Is there any way to "tell" the compiler that the `found` struct's fields might be null even though they are decalared non-nullable?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm aware of both [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#known-pitfalls) and the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425298/why-dont-i-get-a-warning-about-possible-dereference-of-a-null-in-c-sharp-8-with), which explain *why* this happens. But what I'm interested in is *what to do about it*. Specifically, is there any way to tell the compiler that a certain instance field *may be null* even though it is marked non-nullable, without changing the actual declaration of that field to be nullable. Similar to how you can postfix as expression with `!` to tell the compiler, "trust me, this isn't null even though it is marked nullable", I'm looking to do the inverse and say "trust me, this may be null even though it's marked non-nullable". (Bonus points if there's a way to do this automagically with all fields of a struct instance, but I'm doubtful that's possible.)

Comment: which version of c# ?

Comment: going to leave this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: I'm testing with C# 10.0 but I'm pretty sure it's an issue in earlier versions as well.

Comment: ok which configuration of "nullable" is set in the project / file?

Comment: this might be also what you are seeing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#known-pitfalls

Comment: From the "Known pitfalls" section of that doc, it looks like this is a known issue. Still curious if anyone has any strategies for dealing with it.

Comment: `Nullable` is enabled

Comment: Yeah that is definitely what I'm seeing.

Comment: ok, i will let other more knowledgeable people about this subject to pitch in from this point on

Comment: Try creating an array of your struct (I don't have a recent compiler handy).  I'm pretty sure that the default constructor (i.e., the one that nulls every field) will be used.

Comment: There is a proposal to synthase parameterless constructors even when initialized in an array of default . However until then, there is not much you can do and structs are not the usual  first choice in most situations unless benchmarking tells you otherwise. Unfortunately, this all means the language features either with the analysers or otherwise have not caught up to this problem yet. You will need to rethink your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't I get a warning about possible dereference of a null in C# 8 with a class member of a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425298/why-dont-i-get-a-warning-about-possible-dereference-of-a-null-in-c-sharp-8-with)

Comment: @JesseGood I believe that answer is about the same fundamental issue, though I'd argue my question is not *why* it happens but *what to do about it*. I'm starting to suspect, though, that the answer to my question is "You can't do anything about it."

Comment: "trust me, this may be null" sounds like a different way of saying "this field is nullable", which you already know how to do but have rejected. I'm not clear what this "not nullable but sometimes nullable" would be meant to tell the nullability checker but I doubt it would make things any *easier* for it to deduce anything.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Here's an example: A dictionary is a collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` structs. Because of the generic constraints on the dictionary, it is not possible to declare the `TKey` generic parameter as nullable, and because `KeyValuePair` is a system type, I cannot modify it to make the key nullable. But if I call `FirstOrDefault` on a dictionary, the returned `KeyValuePair`'s key value may still be null.

Answer (score 3):

The inverse to the [`!` (null-forgiving) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) is the [[MaybeNull]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.maybenullattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute.

To get this attribute to work in `.netstandard2.0`, you can put a copy of [NullabilityAttributes.cs](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/NullableAttributes.cs,68093cc4b5713519) into your project:

```cs
#if !NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER && !NETSTANDARD2_1_OR_GREATER && !NET5_0_OR_GREATER
namespace System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis{
   // copy of `NullableAttributes.cs` goes here:
   // https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/NullableAttributes.cs,68093cc4b5713519
}
#endif
```

Using the [.NET 6 `NullabilityInfo` APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-6#reflection-apis) shows that the `[MaybeNull]` attribute sets the [`ReadState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.nullabilityinfo.readstate?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-nullabilityinfo-readstate) to `Nullable` while the [`WriteState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.nullabilityinfo.writestate?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-nullabilityinfo-writestate) stays `NotNull`.

For example:

```cs
public readonly struct With_QuestionMark {
    public readonly string? Value;
    public readonly int     Length;

    public With_QuestionMark(object? obj) {
        Value  = obj?.ToString();   // ❌ no warning, because it's OK to assign `null` to `string? Value` 
        Length = Value.Length;      // ✅ warning, because `Value` might be `null`
    }
}

public readonly struct With_MaybeNull {
    [MaybeNull]
    public readonly string Value;
    public readonly int Length;

    public With_MaybeNull(object? obj) {
        Value  = obj?.ToString();   // ✅ warning, because we should never _intentionally_ set `string Value` to `null`
        Length = Value.Length;      // ✅ warning, because `Value` might be `null`
    }
}
```

---

I believe this demonstrates your `KeyValuePair` scenario:

```cs
public static class MaybeNullExample {
    public static void NullableKey() {
        var dic_nullable = new Dictionary<string?, int>();    // ❌ this gives a warning, because `TKey` has a `notnull` constraint
        var key_nullable = dic_nullable.FirstOrDefault().Key; // ✅ implicitly typed to `string?`
        Console.WriteLine(key_nullable.Length);               // ✅ gives the warning we expect
    }

    public static void NonNullKey() {
        var dic_nonnull = new Dictionary<string, int>();    // ✅ no warning, because we satisfy the `notnull` constraint
        var key_nonnull = dic_nonnull.FirstOrDefault().Key; // ❌ implicitly typed to `string`, even though the value is `null`
        Console.WriteLine(key_nonnull.Length);              // ❌ no warning, even though the value is `null`
    }

    public static void MaybeNullKey() {
        // Unfortunately we can't apply attributes to local variables, but we _can_ apply them to local functions
        [return: MaybeNull]
        static string GetKey(KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp) {
            return kvp.Key;
        }

        var dic_maybe = new Dictionary<string, int>();      // ✅ no warning; `notnull` constraint is satisfied
        var key_maybe = GetKey(dic_maybe.FirstOrDefault()); // ✅ implicitly typed to `string?` because of the `[MaybeNull]` attribute
        Console.WriteLine(key_maybe.Length);                // ✅ gives the warning we expect
    }

    ///<remarks>
    /// You can make a generic extension method if you find this occurs often. 
    /// This will preserve the type of `TIn` while still letting the compiler
    /// treat it as nullable.
    ///</remarks>
    [return: MaybeNull]
    static TOut GetMaybeNull<TIn, TOut>(this TIn self, Func<TIn, TOut> extractor) {
        return extractor(self);
    }

    public static void MaybeNullExtension() {
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();                   // ✅ `notnull` constraint is satisfied
        var key = dic.FirstOrDefault().GetMaybeNull(it => it.Key); // ✅ implicitly typed to `string?`
        Console.WriteLine(key.Length);                             // ✅ gives the expected warning
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as explained in my original question, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require modifying the struct itself, because i need to be able to use it with built in structs such as KeyValuePair.

Comment: `[MaybeNull]`, like the `!` operator and all of the other nullability attributes, works in nearly any context where a type is being used. So, any time you would interact with a struct and you want to be safe, you can annotate it with `[MaybeNull]`.

I'll add an example showing what I mean.

Comment: Hmm yeah... This does technically solve the problem, but a local function is kind of a hassle. But it does give me an idea: an extension method would presumably work too, and that would be much less hassle. Thanks!